# Regarding HTaccess and sub directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a question to ask regarding htaccess

I have this structure

```
book
-> read.php
-> avatar
  --> 1
    --> index.html
```

So in the past, I use read.php to serve my content

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

However now, I got my own folder structure with the pre-generated html so they reside in

```
avatar/1/index.html
```

But when I type e.g

avatar/1/2 which is a non existent fodler and file, I wanna use my read.php instead of it trying access the file and folder which return 403.

How can I change my htaccess code to use the read.php with its query string if the folder does not contain index.html

**Thanks**

E.g if I type

```
/book/avatar/2
```

Since there is no /book/avatar/2/index.html (currently it throw me 403 forbidden)

it should use  the htaccess

```
book/read.php?id=$1&num=$2&page=$3
```

-- Updated htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /book

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ chapter.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If i type

```
example.com/book/avatar/2/1
```

It still load chapter.php?id=1

If i type

```
example.com/book/avatar
```

it also load chapter.php?id=1

If i key in this after RewriteCond

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

All files will 404 error

Comment: Please check permissions because the "403" implies some acl or restriction, the htaccess seems good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **`/book/.htaccess`** you can create this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /book/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ chapter.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will handle `/book/avatar/2` OR `/book/avatar` only if request is not a file or directory.

Comment: I think it should be more generic, "avatar" can change i think. Also please

Comment: Can I add this htaccess at /book and not /avatar/.htaccess

Comment: @anubhava , the code above solve the read.php issue. but there 1 issue is if I go for /book/avatar , if /book/avatar does not contain index.html , it should use read.php?id=$1 , how do I make it work from your htacccess

Comment: @anubhava I tried the code give me a 404 not found. but when I remove RewriteRule ^ - [L] , I key in the /book/avatar/1 , it actually load the rule with the single query string ?id=$1

Comment: The RewriteRule ^ - [L] seems to have a problem. Once I remove it I don't have any more 404 error, but it use the rewrite rule of the  ?id=1 even when I have 2 query string.

Comment: @anubhava i update my question with my full htaccess and explanation

Comment: @anubhava, I found the issue, if i load /book/ironman then there no issue (since there no ironman folder), but if I load /book/avatar ( there is issue loading it give me a 403 forbidden because there is a folder /book/avatar, what I wan achieve is if i type /book/avatar return me nothing e.g index.html, it should use the rewrite rules.

Comment: @anubhava, I did that, it show the folder directory instead of using chapter.php to draw the data since there no index.html in that folder, the behavior I wanted is that if there no file at that folder ,it will use the rewrite rules.

Comment: I have already modifier the rules by removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` condition, did you use updated rules?